# Processing : how to set an image to the foreground

Tags: opencv, video, position, processing, foreground

I would like to know if somebody can help me to set an image to the foreground using processing.
I have a sketch where a video is displayed in a continuous loop and above this video, there is an alpha mask to see the video where it is transparent.
Then, the video from the webcam is triggered with an IR proximity sensor. This video is warped with a cylinder, and I would like the video be under the mask because I will enlarge it to fit with the mask.

I search on internet but nothing about it.
I tried to move the lines above, under the video but nothing works. I did it with the previous version when there was no warping and I simply move two lines and it has working. But now I have this warping, nothing works, it drives me crazy...

Thanks so much for your help.
Here my code :

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
EDIT
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Thanks again for your help, and sorry about the link, I didn't know. 
I know how to use a movie/video from the webcam/picture as a texture, that's not my problem. 
The problem I encounter is that I would put a mask above the shape with the texture on it, and I don't know how to do it, I try and search many many things. I'm dealing with this problem since 3 days...
So, here my code where I isolate the problem (MCVE), about the mask, I created it with photoshop: a simple shape with black background and transparency shape in the middle, exported for web in PNG format with transparency.

```
int tubeRes = 32;
float[] tubeX = new float[tubeRes];
float[] tubeY = new float[tubeRes];
PImage img;
PImage masque;

void setup() {
  size(1280, 1024, P3D);
  img = loadImage("berlin-1.jpg");
  masque = loadImage("mask.png");
  float angle = 210.0 / tubeRes;
  for (int i = 0; i < tubeRes; i++) {
    tubeX[i] = cos(radians(i * angle));
    tubeY[i] = sin(radians(i * angle));
  }
  noStroke();
}

void draw() {
  translate(width / 2, height / 2);
  beginShape(QUAD_STRIP);
  texture(img);
  for (int i = 0; i < tubeRes; i++) {
    float x = tubeX[i] * 120;
    float z = tubeY[i] * 100;
    float u = img.width / tubeRes * i;
    vertex(x, -270, z, u, 0);
    vertex(x, 230, z, u, img.height);
  }
  endShape();
  beginShape(QUADS);
  texture(img);
  vertex(0, -100, 0, 0, 0);
  vertex(100, -100, 0, 100, 0);
  vertex(100, 100, 0, 100, 100);
  vertex(0, 100, 0, 0, 100);
  endShape();
  translate(-640, -515);
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5pCEX.png)

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. You'll have better luck if you post a [mcve]. Create a small example program that only shows the problem without any extra code. Hardcode as much as possible. We probably don't need the serial stuff, and we probably don't even need the opencv stuff. Use hardcoded values (and movie files instead of camera feeds) to show the problem, and it'll be much easier for us to help you.

Comment: Hi kevin, thanks for your reply. Sorry about it, here the MCVE. Under the warping image on the cylinder there is the mask. And I would like this mask be above the image on the cylinder. I hope it will help you. Thanks so much again for your reply :)

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0d1J3S0T2RseWJsNVFFZmFGMmM/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to start smaller, and you're going to have to isolate your problems into a simpler sketch. Right now you've got a ton of things going on: playing a video file, camera capture, serial sensors, image masking, and OpenCV logic. That's way too much to debug at one time.

Instead, create a much smaller example sketch that only does one thing. Start with a sketch that simply shows a video playing. When you get that working, then add logic that uses the video as a texture.

Here's an example [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows how to use a video as a texture:

```java
import processing.video.*;

Movie movie;

void setup() {
  size(500, 500, P3D);
  frameRate(30);
  movie = new Movie(this, "DSC_1940.MOV");
  movie.loop();
}

void draw() { 
  
  background(0);

  beginShape();
  texture(movie);

  vertex(mouseX, mouseY, 0, 0);
  vertex(400, 100, movie.width, 0);
  vertex(400, 400, movie.width, movie.height);
  vertex(100, 400, 0, movie.height);

  endShape();
}

void movieEvent(Movie myMovie) {
  myMovie.read();
}
```

Please notice that this is much simpler than your code, and it only does one thing at a time. Start over with something like this, and try to hardcode as much as possible. We don't need to see your serial code, and if possible we don't need to see anything from your webcam or from OpenCV.

Take this example sketch and add logic to use an image mask, or to use a cylinder instead of a square. (But again, don't include any logic that isn't directly related to your problem!) Then when you get stuck, you can post it as an MCVE in a new question. Good luck.

## Edit

If all you're trying to do is mask an image, then you can simply use the `PImage::mask()` function. More info can be found in [the reference](https://processing.org/reference/PImage_mask_.html), but it should be as simple as calling `img.mask(masque)` in your code:

```java
img = loadImage("berlin-1.jpg");
masque = loadImage("mask.png");
img.mask(masque);
```

Then you should be able to use `img` as a texture, and the mask will have already been applied.

However, **your `.png` file doesn't seem to work as a mask!** If I use the `mask.jpg` file from the image masking example (in your Processing editor, go to `File > Examples > Image > Alphamask`, then go to `Sketch > Show Sketch Folder,` then find `mask.jpg` in the `data` directory) or if I save your `.png` file as a `.jpg` file it works okay.

If I save the example `mask.jpg` file as a `.png` file, it works okay. So something is wrong with your file particularly.

Comment: Hi Kevin, thanks again for your reply and your help. I gave you the link to download the sketch (with the data folder) where I isolated the problem with a photo instead of the video for the texture and the mask I would like to use.

Thanks 

Alexandre

Comment: @Alexandre I am behind a firewall that blocks your download link. That's one reason we ask that you put everything in the post itself. But my answer does show you how to use a movie as a texture. If you still can't get it working, I suggest building off of it and posting a new question with an updated MCVE. Good luck.

Comment: Hi Kevin I edited my question with the MCVE, and I add the kind of mask I am using. I hope that will be better :)

Comment: @Alexandre Please see my edited answer. You should be able to use the `PImage.mask()` function, but something seems off with your `.png` mask file.